# How to change price when I enter discount code?

Tags: laravel

I have a cart like this

[image: cart]

When I enter `Discount Code` and click the `Apply` button. The Total Price must be changed, but it did not change.

cart.blade.php

```
<form>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount Code" aria-label="discount_code" name="discount_code">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeDiscount(event, '{{ $cart['id'] }}')">Apply</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

js

```
function changeDiscount(event, id, cartName = null) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var discountCode = document.querySelector('input[name="discount_code"]').value;
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ route('discount.change') }}',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
            coupon: discountCode,
            _method: 'patch'
        }),
        success: function (res) {
            location.reload();
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

web.php

```
Route::patch('/cart/discount/change', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'discountChange'])->name('discount.change');
```

CartController.php

```
use App\Services\Cart\Cart;

public function discountChange(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'coupon' => 'required',
        'id' => 'required',
    ]);
    if(Cart::has($data['id'])) {
        Cart::update($data['id'] , [
            'coupon' => $data['coupon']
        ]);
        $discountCode = $data['coupon'];
        $discount = Discount::query()->where('discount_code', $discountCode)->first();
        if ($discount) {
            $discountPercent = $discount->discount_percent;
            $courses = $discount->courses()->get();
            foreach ($courses as $course) {
                $course->price = $course->price * (1 - $discountPercent / 100);
            }
            $price = number_format($course->price);
            $totalPriceDiscount = "Discounted price: $price";
            return $totalPriceDiscount;
        } else {
            alert()->error('Promotion Code is invalid.')->showConfirm('ok');
        }
        return response(['status' => 'success']);
    }
    return response(['status' => 'error'] , 404);
}
```

Cart.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Cart;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Cart
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cart = session()->get('cart') ?? collect([]);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $value
     * @param null $obj
     * @return $this
     */
    public function put(array $value , $obj = null)
    {
        if(!is_null($obj) && $obj instanceof Model) {
            $value = array_merge($value , [
                'id' => Str::random(10),
                'subject_id' => $obj->id,
                'subject_type' => get_class($obj)
            ]);
        } elseif(!isset($value['id'])) {
            $value = array_merge($value , [
                'id' => Str::random(10)
            ]);
        }
        $this->cart->put($value['id'] , $value);
        session()->put('cart' , $this->cart);
        return $this;
    }

    public function update($key, $options)
    {
        $item = collect($this->get($key, false));
        if (is_numeric($options)) {
            $item = $item->merge([
                'quantity' => $item['quantity'] + $options
            ]);
        }
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $item = $item->merge($options);
        }
        $this->put($item->toArray());
        return $this;
    }

    public function count($key)
    {
        if (!$this->has($key)) return 0;
        return $this->get($key)['quantity'];
    }

    public function has($key)
    {
        if($key instanceof Model) {
            return ! is_null(
                $this->cart->where('subject_id' , $key->id)->where('subject_type' , get_class($key))->first()
            );
        }

        return ! is_null(
            $this->cart->firstWhere('id' , $key)
        );
    }

    public function get($key, $withRelationship = true)
    {
        $item = $key instanceof Model
            ? $this->cart->where('subject_id' , $key->id)->where('subject_type' , get_class($key))->first()
            : $this->cart->firstWhere('id' , $key);

        return $withRelationship ? $this->withRelationshipIfExist($item) : $item;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $cart = $this->cart;
        $cart = $cart->map(function($item) {
            return $this->withRelationshipIfExist($item);
        });

        return $cart;
    }

    protected function withRelationshipIfExist($item)
    {
        if(isset( $item['subject_id'] ) && isset($item['subject_type']) ) {
            $class = $item['subject_type'];
            $subject = (new $class())->find( $item['subject_id'] );

            $item[strtolower(class_basename($class))] = $subject;

            unset($item['subject_id']);
            unset($item['subject_type']);

            return $item;
        }
        return $item;
    }

    public function delete($key)
    {
        if ($this->has($key)) {
            $this->cart = $this->cart->filter(function ($item) use ($key){
                if ($key instanceof Model) {
                    return ($item['subject_id'] != $key->id ) && ($item['subject_type'] != get_class($key));
                }
                return $key != $item['id'];
            });
            session()->put('cart', $this->cart);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function flush()
    {
        $this->cart = collect([]);
        session()->put('cart', $this->cart);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I click the apply button, I see this in the console in the network tab.

[image: console]

And I have three tables,

- courses
- discounts
- course_discount

How to pass .totalPrices and #totalAll?

[image]